# Line-break in ToolTipTitle and ToolTipDescription of ribbon

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, ribbon

Is there any way to break a line in ToolTipTitle and ToolTipDescription of a MS CRM 2011 Ribbon?
The code below puts a line break just in the title, but not in the tooltip texts (texts of tooltip are “onetwo” using this code):

```xml
<Button Id="tmpBut" Command="tmpCmd" 
LabelText="one&#x200b;&#x200b;two" 
ToolTipTitle="one&#x200b;&#x200b;two" 
ToolTipDescription="one&#x200b;&#x200b;two" 
TemplateAlias="isv" Image16by16="/_imgs/ribbon/Activate_16.png" 
Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/Activate_32.png" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested, however a search of the [CRM SDK (Community) content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328323.aspx) suggests this for the Description attribute:

```
&#x0a;&#x0d;
```

Comment: Tested. Works (for description). Thanks. (Looking at the page, it seems I foolishly missed the community content.)